# Bigquery to pubsub message push using dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

We have requirement to push data from Bigquery to pubsub as event using dataflow.Do we have any template available for the same ( as I understand pubsub to BQ with DF template is available). If we use dataflow streaming mechanism is set to true - do we need any scheduler to invoke dataflow to fetch and push data to pubsub? Please guide me on this.

Comment: Which volume of data do you want to inject in PubSub at each query?

Comment: It would be ~10KB for each query

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a template to push BigQuery rows to PubSub. In addition, the streaming mode works only when PubSub is the source, not the sink. When it's a database, or a file, it's always in batch mode.

---

For your use case, I recommend you to use a simple Cloud Functions or Cloud Run and to trigger it with Cloud Scheduler. The data volume is low, and a serverless product perfectly fit your use case. No need of a big and scalable product like Dataflow

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to export BigQuery table to json files into cloud storage.
(Or may be, if your write to BQ is not heavy, when you write to BigQuery, write also json files into cloud storage into dated folders)

Then use text files to pub sub dataflow template.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#text-files-on-cloud-storage-to-pubsub-stream